# CD/DVD drive not detected Windows 7 (HP Elitebook 2540p)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, dvd

After multiple BSODs, I was forced to re-install Windows 7 on my HP Elitebook 2540p. After a few struggles, most hardware works again except for the CD/DVD drive which does not appear in `Windows Explorer` or in `Device Manager`.

I've carefully following the recommendations in this [HP support article](https://support.hp.com/hr-en/document/c01895589). In particular:

- Installed as many drivers as would install from [the HP website](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-2540p-notebook-pc/4138624)
- The CD/DVD option appears in the BIOS > Boot options
- The CD/DVD drive physically opens and closes when the button on the outside of the drive is pressed
- In HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}, the `LowerFilters` and `UpperFilters` registry keys do not exist
- The CD/DVD drive option does not appear in `Device Manager`

The CD/DVD drive worked before the re-installation of Windows. This may be relevant, but one of the drivers (`Intel Matrix Storage Manager Driver, sp48491.exe`) would not install with the message `This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software`.

I'm at a loss what to try next...what else can I try?

Comment: `Intel Matrix Storage Manager Driver` is a RAID driver and has nothing to do with your CD/DVD device not working.  You shouldn't install it unless you have a RAID.

Comment: @Ramhound: OK, thanks. That explains the error messsage - since there is no RAID hardware, the driver package was not installed. However, the description of the driver included several mentions of `Serial ATA` devices which the laptop should have. Is there any way (that you know of) to manually install the CD/DVD drive?

Comment: Windows 7 has built-in SATA support, the drivers are unnecessary, but what your attempted to install was an Intel RAID driver, if this was a fresh install of Windows 7, it probably doesn’t have all updates installed.  I wasn’t able to find the file you attempted to use so I cannot research it, but it’s still unrelated to your problem